# Check if two fields already have an exact match when submitting data to a database with bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, sql, twitter-bootstrap

I am making an extremely simple app that is for our department's weekly college football pickem. We pick one game per weekend, then place bets on who will win and what the total combined score will be. We needed a spot to do this without seeing everyone elses predictions, as that gives late participators a huge advantage.

I already have a simple html page and local db that displays DB entries, showing the employee name and the date submitted. When creating an entry, you enter your name, prediction of the winner, the combined total score, and the date. It doesn't display the predictions details until Fridays at 2PM, while also locking any new submissions, so that no one can base their predictions off of what everyone else has.

My problem is I'm trying to make it check to make sure that someone else doesn't have the exact same Winner+Score combo when clicking submit on the create page. Somehow it just needs to scan those two DB attributes to make sure no one else has the exact same value for those. There's usually only going to be around 10 people participating. Here is my code for the create page.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
 {
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Pick</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.winner, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.winner, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.winner, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.points, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.points, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.points, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.postDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.postDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.postDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

I just need the submit button to tell them that they can't submit those values, or either just disable it until they have values that aren't an exact match.

Answer (score 0):

What about sending it on controller and check values here, then you can put if condition and check values, if they matches, redirect back with message, which you can store for example in:

`ViewData["Message"] = "Your message";`

And then use data:

```
<h3>Passing Data From Controller to View using ViewBag</h3>  
@{   
    var data = ViewBag.Message;  
}  
<h3>Id: @data.Id</h3>  
<h3>RecordName: @data.RecordName</h3>  
<h3>RecordDetail: @data.RecordDetail</h3>
```

Example webpage:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc-passing-data-from-controller-to-view/